# IP address for AWS Lightsail container services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I know you cannot use static IP for an AWS Lightsail container services.

But AFAIK there is an IPv6 address for the container service. Where can i find this? I do not see in anywhere in de web console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the public domain of the Lightsail Container Service to get the IP address as follows:

```
host <public-domain>
```

You can find the public-domain name in the Lightsail console and just use it in any terminal to obtain the IP address. You will get several IP addresses corresponding to the number of your nodes in your service + control plane.

Given that the service is most likely running a Kubernetes cluster in the background, the IP address is not shown because it is actually several IP addresses depending on the number of nodes in your service.